# Error "Invalid public key given to Commerce.js client"

Tags: reactjs, api, import, export, e-commerce

I'm fetching data from commercejs.com and my localhost shows some error as "*Invalid public key given to Commerce.js client*". I choose the public api key one tho

This is my `commerce.js`:

```js
import Commerce from '@chec/commerce.js';

export const commerce = new Commerce(process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

This is my env:

```
REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_32015299720e5050ac997c8e08a77c1a0e24bf21215b7
```

Comment: dude why are you exposing your keys, on a public platform

Comment: the error message says itself that the public key is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Your API key is not being provided to Commerce.js when you construct Commerce.

```
import { Commerce } from '@chec/commerce.js';

const commerce = new Commerce('put_your_api_key_here');
```

When using an environment variable, be sure that it is being loaded correctly. In this case please ensure that the `.env` file in your project is in the project root folder (same level as `package.json`), and that it has the environment variable defined correctly as referenced by your code. e.g.

```
const commerce = new Commerce(process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY);
```

project

```
- node_modules
- src
-.env
-.gitignore
- README.md
- package.json
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put .env file in your project root

https://commercejs.com/docs/community/faq/

Comment: it's in my project root but i'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorial.

Try two things:

- Restart your local server. Stop with CTRL+C, then run `npm start`.
- Try using your Public Key (not test key).

Anyone else with issues, double check you've spelled everything correctly in `commerce.js`. I had written `REACT_APP_CHECK` instead of `CHEC`.